# How to allocate a large array in the linux kernel?

Tags: memory, linux-kernel

I'm writing a device mapper target.

I need to allocate a large array of ~30 byte records.

Right now I'm using flex_array for testing, but it seems to be limited to 4MB on 32-bit and 2MB on 64-bit. http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/flex_array.h

The size limit seems to be due to the code being limited to one level of indirection.

Is there something like flex_array that has multiple levels of indirection? I could probably hack something together but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if there is something already in.

Comment: And you are not using *vmalloc()* due to...?

Comment: @0andriy Low total space by default, especially on ARM.